# KOMA scrartcl indent by section

Tags: luatex, koma-script, scrartcl

so I know this is not that of a best practice but I have a template that I need to reproduce and words makes it easy to do so....
I need to indent the full text (not just `\parindent`) depending on the level. I need to set this for heading and text separately, e.g.

1. **Section, Heading** (inl. number) at left margin
2. **Section, Text** indented 0.7cm from left margin
3. **Subsection, Heading** on text with section, e.g. indented 0.7cm from left margin
4. **Subsectin, Text** indented 1.4cm from left margin

Is there an easy way to accomplish this using KOMA?

Current State of the document

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4]{scrartcl}

% Packages, Design
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=1.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepackage{showframe}

% Section style
\setkomafont{section}{\bfseries\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\bfseries}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-2\baselineskip,
afterskip=0.2\baselineskip,
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
beforeskip=-2\baselineskip,
afterskip=0.2\baselineskip
]{subsection, subsubsection}

% Opening
\title{Report}
\author{A Anme}

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1}
Text\\
More text on a second line\par
\lipsum
\section{Test 2}
Text\\
Equation: 
\begin{equation}
    E = m\cdot c^2
\end{equation}
\subsection{Test 2 2}
Text
\subsubsection{TestSub}
Something

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing something like this, is not as trivial as it seems. The left margin is a value used always for the whole page. So to add extra left margin, you could either move the whole content of a sub…section into an environment, e.g., an indented `minipage` (issue: no page break), or an `addmargin`, or maybe even a `tcolorbox`, or you can manipulate the `\leftskip`. In the following example, I do the last (and use generic hooks of LaTeX from 2020/10/01) and additionally redefine `\sectionlinesformat` (see the KOMA-Script manuals for more information about this):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}% All default options removed

% Packages, Design
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.2cm, right=1.6cm]{geometry}% left
                                % margin increased by the text indent of
                                % sections

\usepackage{mwe}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepackage{showframe}

% Section style
\setkomafont{section}{\bfseries\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\bfseries}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \hskip#2\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth+0.7cm}{%
    \@hangfrom{#3}{#4}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  indent=-0.7cm,
  runin=false,
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=0.2\baselineskip,% IMHO not enough
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  indent=0cm,
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=0.2\baselineskip,% IMHO not enough
]{subsection, subsubsection}

\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{%
  \par
  \setlength{\leftskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}%
}
\AddToHook{cmd/subsection/before}{%
  \par
  \setlength{\leftskip}{0.7cm}%
  \setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}%
  \addtolength{\linewidth}{-\leftskip}%
}

% Opening
\title{Report}
\author{A Anme}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Test 1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}
\item Testitem
\item Testitem
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2-3]

\section{Test 2}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
    E = m\cdot c^2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Test 2 2}
\lipsum[3]
\subsubsection{TestSub}
\lipsum[4]

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

At page 1 and 2 this seems to fit the request:

[image: page 1 and 2 with the requested indents]

But the indent of the lists at page 3 and 4 is not correct:

[image: two pages with wrong list indent]

If this is relevant for you, you should also have to change `\leftmargini` etc. within the hooks. Alternatively you could use package `enumitem` to adapt the lists.

There may be other issues with changing `\leftskip` for almost the complete document. For example environments derived from `trivlist` like `addmargin` could also *behave strange*.

So IMHO, the answer to your question

> Is there an easy way to accomplish this using KOMA?

would be: No, not easy.

Comment: Thanks, that dies exactly what I want at this time! I will patch the lists with enumitem and see if I can change the layout request in the future since Im not a fan of the layout itself

Comment: FWIW: I fixed the lists with the following which is fairly easy (customindent is defined as the 0.7cm):
`
\setlist[enumerate]{
 leftmargin=\dimexpr(\leftskip + \customindent)\relax,
}
\setlist[itemize]{
 leftmargin=\dimexpr(\leftskip + \customindent)\relax,
}
`